Rounding off for positive & negative values?
I am trying to build a function that can return correct rounding off for both positive and negative values.
Here is my requirement
Input       Output
-1.8550     -1.86
1.8550       1.86
-1384.8540   -1384.85
1384.8540     1384.85
-1384.8550   -1384.86
-1384.8560   -1384.86
-3203.8640   -3203.86 

I tried below, but its not working.!


var customRoundOff = function(value) {
  debugger;
  var valueSign = Math.sign(value);
  var numericalPart = Math.abs(Number((value + "").split(".")[0]));
  var decPart = (value + "").split(".")[1];

  if (decPart && numericalPart) {
    var pntedDecimal = Number('0.' + decPart);
    var roundedDecimal = pntedDecimal.toFixed(2);
    var roundedValue = numericalPart + roundedDecimal;
    
    console.log("pntedDecimal", pntedDecimal);
    console.log("roundedDecimal", roundedDecimal);
    console.log("numericalPart", numericalPart);
    console.log("roundedValue", roundedValue);
    
    return roundedValue * valueSign; // Returns float
  } else {
    return value.toFixed(2); // Returns string
  }
}

customRoundOff(-1.8550);




Why is this so complicated? What do you need that's different from just value.toFixed(2)?

That isn't how you define a function in JS. Check your syntax

@RoryMcCrossan Except for the missing } (probably just a copying error) what's wrong with the syntax?

I didn't dig to far in to it, but it seems to work in isolation, but not when called in a loop over an array that I was using to test with: https://jsfiddle.net/26bh9ndr/

I now know what is wrong with a simple +n.toFixed(2):
it returns faulty values for the first two test cases -1.8550 and 1.8550 !!!


const
    round = n => {
        const sign = Math.sign(n);
        return sign * (Math.abs(n) + 0.000999999999).toFixed(2);
    },
    rnd = n => +n.toFixed(2),
    values = [-1.8550, 1.8550, -1384.8540, 1384.8540, -1384.8550, -1384.8560, -3203.8640];
    
console.log(JSON.stringify(values.map(round)));  // Nina's solution
console.log(JSON.stringify(values.map(rnd)));    // mine --> **wrong**



However, the .toFixed() error is not as fundamental as I initially feared. It is basically another manifestation of the limited floating point number accuracy in JavaScript, see here for further details.
When looking closer at the problem we find the following:


const round = (n,small=0.000999999999) => {
   const sign = Math.sign(n);
   return sign * (Math.abs(n) + small).toFixed(2);
  },
  rnd = n => +n.toFixed(2);

[-1.85500001,-1.855, 
 -1.85499999].forEach(v=>
 console.log(v,round(v),rnd(v),round(v,0.000000000001))
);  



So, Nina's statement that ".toFixed(2) switches at 0.006 to 0.01" needs to be corrected to something like: ".toFixed() switches at 0.00500000000001 (or some similarly small amount above 0.005) to 0.01". And, although her approach in round() is correct, the small number 0.000999999999 she adds to the intermediate result needs to be reduced to something like 0.000000000001.

not for me with  edge ...

so, you do not see any difference at the results ?

i get [-1.86,1.86,-1384.85,1384.85,-1384.86,-1384.86,-3203.86], [-1.85,1.85,-1384.85,1384.85,-1384.86,-1384.86,-3203.86], which is not the same.

Another alternative is using Intl.NumberFormat if string output is not a problem.


const arrNumbers=[-1.8550 ,1.8550, -1384.8540, 1384.8540, -1384.8550, 1384.8550, -3203.8640];

for (var i=0 ; i<arrNumbers.length; i++){
    console.log(
      new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', { maximumFractionDigits: 2 }).format(arrNumbers[i])
    )
}




Add Number.EPSILON multiplied with the sign to your number before rounding.


const myRound = n => Number((n + Math.sign(n) * Number.EPSILON).toFixed(2))

console.log(myRound(1.8550))
console.log(myRound(-1.8550))




toFixed() works correct! The problem is when scanning numbers.
(1.8550).toPrecision(18)  // => output: "1.85499999999999998" 
(-1.8550).toPrecision(18) // => output: "-1.85499999999999998"

Number 1.8550 does not exist. So scanning of the number results in the nearest existing floating number 1.85499999999999998. And the result of this number with toFixed(2) is the string "1.85"!!
Conclusion:
All user-defined functions that round the number 1.8550 to "1.86" are invalid. This statement can be verified by using 1.85499999999999998 as input.
